# Creating an if statement variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, return

I am trying to create a variable that will enable me to echo out the response from the correct section of my HTML but I am unsure how I would start this of.

```
if($var == $var2)
{
  $var3
}else{
 echo 'images not found';
}
```

Comment: @KhaleelAKarim its from an XML feed ["photo"]=> array(43) { [0] so yes its an array

Comment: add comment to the answers if they are not usefull, so it can help others get the right answer to you

Comment: This is bar far not the first question you ask about the very basic if statement. It's time you actually start learning the basics of the programming language you're using. http://php.net/if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```
$result = '';    

if($var == $var2)
{
    foreach($var3 as $img) {
        $result .= '<img ...>';
    }
}else{
   $result = 'images not found';
}
```

And then you can just echo the `$result` variable

Answer (score 1):

to do this , you can simply write :

```
if($var == $var2)
{
    foreach ($var3 as $img)
        echo "<img src='".$img."' />";
}else{
echo 'images not found';
}
```

What's your problem with this?